# Simplifying $ \sum_{1\cdot m_1 + 2\cdot m_2 + \cdots + n \cdot m_n = n} \frac{1}{m_1 ! m_2 ! \cdots m_n !} t^{m_1 + \cdots + m_n} $

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, multinomial-coefficients, multinomial-theorem

Does anybody know how to simplify the expression like the following?

> $$ \sum_{1\cdot m_1 + 2\cdot m_2 + \cdots + n \cdot m_n = n} \frac{1}{m_1 ! m_2 ! \cdots m_n !} t^{m_1 + \cdots + m_n} $$

This looks unusual to me since the summation is usually taken over $n$-tuples satisfying $m_1 + \cdots + m_n = n$.

Comment: The form looks like something out of [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula)

Comment: It's the coefficient of $x^n$ in the power-series expansion of $e^{t(x+x^2+\ldots+x^n)}$

Comment: Yeah I got this expression while applying Faa di Bruno's formula to the function $ e^{\frac{t}{2} \frac{1+x}{1-x}} $.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "*the summation*" in "*the summation is usually taken over*" partitions in list-of-parts notation rather than in frequency notation. You could rewrite in that form if you want, but you'd have to use Iverson bracket notation and sums to extract the $m_i$.